# solving determinants by method of recurrent relations

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading the Linear Algebra Solutions Manual and there are some things I can't quite get around recurrently defined determinants.

We have a determinant which is also a recurrent relation
$\Delta_n =p\Delta_{n-1} + q\Delta_{n-2}$

We represent $p$ and $q$ in the form of $p=\alpha+\beta$ and $q=-\alpha\beta$ i.e. $p$ and $q$ are the roots of the quadratic equation $x^2-px-q=0$.

After substituting in the first equation we get $\Delta_n =(\alpha+\beta)\Delta_{n-1} - \alpha\beta\Delta_{n-2}$

We get that there's a geometric progression in the last equation and by writing all down we get that

$$
\Delta_n=\frac{\beta^{n-1}(\Delta_2-\alpha\Delta_1)-\alpha^{n-1}(\Delta_2-\beta\Delta_1)}{\beta-\alpha}
$$

Now, here's the thing I don't understand. In the book it is written that the last formula is easily remembered with the formula $$\Delta_n=c_1\alpha^n+c_2\beta^n$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are taken from the same with $n=1, n=2$.

I really don't get how we got this representation using $c_1$ and $c_2$ and what exactly $c_1$ and $c_2$ actually equal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part of your calculation you showed that $\Delta_n=c_1\alpha^n+c_2\beta^n$ for some $c_1,c_2$. How to find them? If you plug in $n=1,2$:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\Delta_1 = c_1\alpha+c_2\beta \\
\Delta_2 = c_1\alpha^2+c_2\beta^2 \\
\end{array}
$$

and you can compute $c_1,c_2$ from this system of two equations.

Personally I think it is even easier to take $n=0$ and the equation $\Delta_0=c_1+c_2$.

Comment: Where have I shown that?

Comment: @Nikola in the long equation just under "We get that"

Comment: I guess what I dont get is how first term can be expressed with the second.